# How to get input value after it has been changed by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to get the value of .qty input field but I have a problem that another jQuery function is rewriting the entered value after it gets entered.

For instance, if I enter 1, it gets rounded to 3,3360 but multiplied by 1 so I only can get the written value but I need the value that is changed after (3,3360) and the result should be 33.36 not 10.00:

```js
function myFunctionupdateqtyinput() {
  var x = document.getElementById("quantity_60269d6f09cd1");
  var a = 3.336;
  var b = x.value;

  var d = b - (b % a) + a;
  var f = d.toPrecision(5);
  x.value = f;
}

if ($(".kpt-product-count").length) {
  function checkForCount() {
    var single_count = parseFloat($(".kpt-product-count").data('kptcount'));
    var qty = parseFloat($(".qty").val());


    var total = (qty * single_count);
    total = total.toFixed(2);


    if (isNaN(total)) {
      total = single_count.toFixed(2);

    }

    $(".kpt-product-count-text").find('span').html(total);

  }


  $(".qty").on('input', checkForCount);
}
```

```css
@import url("https://tonicuk.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-layout.css");
@import url("https://tonicuk.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-smallscreen.css");
@import url("https://tonicuk.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css");

.quantity .qty {
  height: 34px;
}

.quantitym2 .qty {
  width: 90;
  margin-right: 10;
}


.kpt-product-count {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.kpt-product-count-label {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.quantitym2 input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity quantitym2">
  <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_60269d6f09cd1">Boost quantity</label>
  <input type="number" onchange="myFunctionupdateqtyinput()" id="quantity_60269d6f09cd1" class="input-text qty text" value="3.336" step="0.0001" min="0.0001" max="" name="quantity" title="title" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="">
</div>

<div class="kpt-product-count" data-kptcount="10">
  <div class='kpt-product-count-label'>In total: </div>
  <div class='kpt-product-count-text'> <span>10</span> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function `myFunctionupdateqtyinput()`inside the checkForCount function

```
function checkForCount() {
    myFunctionupdateqtyinput();
```

```js
function myFunctionupdateqtyinput() {
  var x = document.getElementById("quantity_60269d6f09cd1");
  var a = 3.336;
  var b = x.value;

  var d = b - (b % a) + a;
  var f = d.toPrecision(5);
  x.value = f;
}

if ($(".kpt-product-count").length) {
  function checkForCount() {
    myFunctionupdateqtyinput();
    var single_count = parseFloat($(".kpt-product-count").data('kptcount'));
    var qty = parseFloat($(".qty").val());


    var total = (qty * single_count);
    total = total.toFixed(2);


    if (isNaN(total)) {
      total = single_count.toFixed(2);

    }

    $(".kpt-product-count-text").find('span').html(total);

  }


  $(".qty").on('input', checkForCount);
}
```

```css
@import url("https://tonicuk.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-layout.css");
@import url("https://tonicuk.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-smallscreen.css");
@import url("https://tonicuk.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css");
.quantity .qty {
  height: 34px;
}

.quantitym2 .qty {
  width: 90;
  margin-right: 10;
}

.kpt-product-count {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.kpt-product-count-label {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.quantitym2 input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity quantitym2">
  <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_60269d6f09cd1">Boost quantity</label>
  <input type="number" onchange="myFunctionupdateqtyinput()" id="quantity_60269d6f09cd1" class="input-text qty text" value="3.336" step="0.0001" min="0.0001" max="" name="quantity" title="title" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="">
</div>

<div class="kpt-product-count" data-kptcount="10">
  <div class='kpt-product-count-label'>In total: </div>
  <div class='kpt-product-count-text'> <span>10</span> </div>
</div>
```